# Intellij prints an unknown character for semicolon

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij when I type semicolon it prints some special character  ö .
Anyone has faced this issue before? If yes how to fix this?

Logs:

```
2020-10-01 16:47:29,809 [257965913]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - Start shutting down C:\Users\--------------------------------------
2020-10-01 16:47:29,813 [257965917]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - Finished shutting down C:\Users\--------------------------------------
2020-10-01 16:47:29,818 [257965922]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2020-10-01 16:47:29,825 [257965929]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped 
2020-10-01 16:47:35,734 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2020-10-01 16:47:35,785 [     51]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-202.6397.94, 27 Jul 2020 16:09) 
2020-10-01 16:47:35,787 [     53]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2020-10-01 16:47:35,787 [     53]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.7+10-b944.20 (JetBrains s.r.o.) 
2020-10-01 16:47:35,788 [     54]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.7+10-b944.20 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2020-10-01 16:47:35,789 [     55]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: exit -Xms128m -Xmx1023m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Users\-------\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2\idea64.exe.vmoptions -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\jbr\\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\jbr\\bin\server -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2020.2 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\-------\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\-------\java_error_in_idea.hprof 
2020-10-01 16:47:35,789 [     55]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - library path: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\jbr\\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\jbr\\bin\server 
2020-10-01 16:47:35,790 [     56]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - boot library path: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\jbr\bin 
2020-10-01 16:47:35,797 [     63]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - locale=en_US JNU=Cp1252 file.encoding=Cp1252
  idea.config.path=C:\Users\----\IdeaIC2020.2
  idea.system.path=C:\Users\----\IdeaIC2020.2
  idea.plugins.path=C:\Users\---\IdeaIC2020.2\plugins
  idea.log.path=C:\Users\-------\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2\log
```

Comment: Please attach idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE.

Comment: any particular log? It is a big file.. So I can copy paste something specific

Comment: After restart it is working